# Could not find Qt4

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, qt4, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was installing ROS-fuerte on Fedora 17 (64bit) when I encountered this issue. The error message says that it cannot find Qt4, though I did install it. Please help.

```
$>  cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF

...
-- +++ ros_tutorials
-- Building stack ros_tutorials
-- rospy_tutorials: 2 messages
-- Boost version: 1.48.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   thread
-- roscpp_tutorials: 0 messages
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) (found suitable version "4.8.4", required is "4.6")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1200 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  ros_tutorials/turtlesim/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65265/could-not-find-qt4/) by [Hiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/5162/hiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-06-17**:
Just to make sure; you are following an instruction that's specifically [designated for 17(&16)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Fedora#Installing_on_Fedora_16_and_17) right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the given error message, the issue doesn't seem to be rooted in `ROS` itself; instead I suspect that it's more about how `Qt` is installed.

Some links tell that you need to check (and add if necessary) if `Qt` is in environment variable:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020797/how-to-get-qt4-for-a-cmake-build
- http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17482

HTH

---

Update 6/17/2013) Not yet sure the solution/workaround but the cause of the bizarre error might be that [ros_tutorials/turtlesim/CMakeLists.txt:7](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/hydro-devel/turtlesim/CMakeLists.txt#L7) asks for `Qt 4.6`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like something is asking for Qt 4.6 but you have 4.8.4  You will need to find what's asking for 4.6 specifically and see if it's possible to upgrade.  Fedora is probably ahead of the Ubuntu version.

Note: those names are not environment variables.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/5162/hiro/) on 2013-06-18**:
Thank you very much for your reply. I followed Issac's off-line suggestion to edit ros_tutorials/turtlesim/CMakeLists.txt to specify version 4.8, but I still got the same error.

**Comment by [Hiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/5162/hiro/) on 2013-06-18**:
So I deleted ros_tutorials/turtlesim (this is another suggestion by Issac) and the cmake worked. I am currently getting stuck at "make install" due to a permission error saying that:

**Comment by [Hiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/5162/hiro/) on 2013-06-18**:
...that "error: could not create 'build': Permission denied
CMake Error at catkin/CMakeFiles/safe_execute_install.cmake:5 (message):
Error executing process with arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
catkin/cmake_install.cmake:183 (INCLUDE)
cmake_install.cmake:37 (INCLUDE)

**Comment by [Hiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/5162/hiro/) on 2013-06-18**:
Probably this is just a local issue, but I don't know why I get this error even though I sudo to run make.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-18**:
You should *never* sudo make.  If you do it once you will always have to do it, and you then don't have any protection from accidental things.